# Cannot save file after opening it

Tags: c#, .net, drawing

I can save my file infinitely. I can open my file infinitely. And I can save then open my file.

However I cannot save my file after opening it. I get the following error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

I tried disposing and temp bitmaps, but that did not seem to work for me. The location the file is being opened and saved is also the same place, so perhaps maybe the problem is overwriting a file? My program always breaks at the temp.save

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Graphics.FromImage(bmap).Dispose();
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmap))
            {

                bmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Nick\final.bmp");
                g.DrawImage(bmap, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            }
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }
 private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmap);
            temp =new Bitmap(bmap);
            //Graphics.FromImage(bmap).Dispose();
            try
            {
                g.Dispose();          
                temp.Save(@"C:\Users\Nick\final.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); ;
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: is the `bmap` a private field?

Comment: Nope. `Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap`. Although I just tested and I still get the error, whether it is public or private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overwrite the file, because when you use `new Bitmap(path)` the file will be loaded in memory and keep it open until you're done with it, you can't overwrite a file if it's currently open.

***EDIT***

Here is how you load the image from a memory stream:

```
// make sure you don't dispose of this until you're done with it
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
Image img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
```

Comment: I am trying to close this file , then delete it, but I can't figure out a way to close it. And I can't just delete it.

Comment: Have you tried loading the file from a memory stream, then delete it ?

Comment: Not yet. Let me look into this.

Comment: Perfect. Memory stream allowed me to dispose and close the file.

Comment: Is it not possible to close the file without memory stream?

Comment: Well, no I don't think so since when you open the file using `Bitmap.FromFile(path);` it keeps it open and when you try to overwrite it an exception will be thrown (since the file is currently in use). I did some edits of my answer and included some details.